# how to update a fragment from another fragment

Tags: android

I have fragemnt in which several buttons layaut and picture. In creating this fragment on top of the loaded data. in the lower part of the site for other fragments. One of the fragments contains a list. When I click on an item list, I need to update data on a fragment that contains this fragment. This hour I just create a new fragment the parent with the new parameters derived from the list. But I think it's not right. tell me how to update the fragment.ie I update the data and set to the desired form elements, but how to update the GUI itself

[image]

example may be easier

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add interfaces to the fragment and implement them in your activity. Interfaces are good way to communicate between fragments. Take a look at [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). In the implemented interface write code appropriately to change other fragments.

Comment: there is an example code in the android training link above. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Using Interfaces for InterFragment communication should do the job for you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyyGP_d0Ia8&index=8&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo

Look into the below video, It might help you.